# How to vertically align the text into a coloured div using CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml

I need to vertically align the text into a div that have a certain height.

If you go here you can see my problem: http://onofri.org/example/example3/

As you can see I have a **#titleBox** div that contain the text: **Promoting Investment in Agriculture**

The **#titleBox** have a specific height that is 40px. I want vertically align the text in the green div in such a way that is at the center.

This is my HTML and CSS code but don't work well:

```
<div id="container">


    <div id="titleBox">
        <p id="myTitle">Promoting Investment in Agriculture</p>
    </div>


</div>

#titleBox{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #6da662;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}



#myTitle{
    /* consente di posizionare un elemento al centro del suo contenitore */
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

What have I to do to solve?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add these styles to `#myTitle`:

```
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 40px;
```

Comment: WOW seems to work fine !!! Also I tryed to add the vertical-aligned: middle; property on the #myTitle but I did not use the line-height property. Why using it work? What exactly do? Tnx so much

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution - add these styles to your page.
You should definitely get familiar with the display:table-cell property for vertical centering.

```
#titleBox{
    display:table;
}

#myTitle{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that in order to horizontally center `#myTitle`, you need the parent container with `display: table` since `margin: 0 auto` will center a table cell.  For vertical centering, table-cells are more versatile than the line-height trick, especially for multi-line text. Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/MUXEd/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be really concise, you can do it all in one element:

```
<div id="titleBox">Promoting Investment in Agriculture</div>
```

and apply the following CSS:

```css
#titleBox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #6da662;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/2PxsZ/